# Segment free space SQL script doesn't work in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following script that showed me, when using Oracle 9i database, if one or more segments in a tablespace were getting full (holding account of the auto-extent also).

After upgrading the database to 10g it returns nothing, even if the segments are full.

Why doesn't it work anymore? What modifications should I make in order for it to work?

This is the script:

```
SELECT rpad(s.owner,10) "Owner",
  rpad(s.segment_type,12) "Tip segment",
  rpad(s.segment_name,25) "Nume segment",
  rpad(tablespace_name,15) "Tablespace",
  s.next_extent * ( 1 + s.pct_increase / 100 )/1024 "Urmatorul extent"
FROM dba_segments s
WHERE 2*s.next_extent * ( 1 + s.pct_increase / 100 ) >
            ( SELECT MAX( f.bytes )
                   FROM dba_free_space f
                   WHERE f.tablespace_name = s.tablespace_name )
order by 1,2
```

Comment: How do you know the query should return any data? What other queries have you run that indicate there are "full segments"? Without access to your dba_segments and dba_free_space data it's kind of hard to tell what should be happening...

Comment: It seems likely that the `WHERE` clause is no longer being satisfied. Comment out the `WHERE` clause and see what's returned.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change from dictionary managed tablespaces to locally managed tablespaces?  Certainly by 10g (which is an odd thing to upgrade to since it's been desupported for a few years), locally managed tablespaces were the default.  If memory serves, locally managed tablespaces were still the preferred approach in 9i but that's long enough ago that I wouldn't trust my memory.

A locally managed tablespace, by definition, has a NULL `pct_increase`.  That would cause your `WHERE` clause to not return a row (the expression `2*s.next_extent * ( 1 + s.pct_increase / 100 )` would evaluate to NULL).